# Paypal SDK Payment and Execute Payment

Tags: php, paypal

Im recently using paypal php sdk.

I need to charge $x for customers.. but u dont understand the circuit process.

1. I need to crate de paypal payment
2. I redirect the user to paypal plataform
3. It redirects again to my site
4. I need to run Execute payment

I dont understan the step 4.

a) what happend if i dont run this script
b) how can it be that I can change all my order information on the execute payment.. for example. the user approves u$20 ann now I charge it for u$300.

I dont understand.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: By *execute payment*, I'm assuming they mean add the details to your database, and do what you need to complete the payment (send an email, give them points, add something to a log to be shipped out etc)

Comment: I thank something like that... like an IPN flow.. but I made a sandbox payment and didnt make the "Execute Payment" and when I list my payments this last payment doesnt appair !!

Comment: did you figure this out ?